# I include Android support library compat, but I can't get rid of the abc_* layout and other things I don't really need. How to get rid of them?

Tags: android, apk, proguard, android-support-library

If we include the Android support library like this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

For a simple hello world project: single constrict layout with a text view, the final APK (even after proguard), will include all the layout resources (e.g. abc_alert_dialog_material.xml) from library.

How to get rid of them? I have already use

> minifyEnabled true

and

> shrinkResources true

and I even used this in resources xml

> tools:discard="@layout/abc_*"

I am 100% sure I do not use abc_alert_dialog (and many others). I see aapt_rules.txt include this:

```
# Referenced at /Users/csing/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/1487dd2b28ee6f463f28fac491292503/res/layout/abc_alert_dialog_material.xml:0
-keep class android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView { <init>(...); }
```

Is there anyway to tell via proguard rule "I do not want NestedScrollView nor do I want any of abc_alert_dialog_material.xml"?

Comment: That's a framework class, I don't think you can strip it.  And even if you can, are you sure nothing uses it?  For example, ListViewCompat derives from it.

Comment: I thought they're library, not really a framework (like it's burn to the device). Anyway, I also tried R8, same results. Now my next trial is to take the whole library and compile myself... 8>